# how to set control to occupy several grid cells?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want a control to take 2 cells: column 3 and column 4 of the same row . how to do that? I've tried that but it doesn't work:

```
Grid.Column="4-5"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Grid.Column="4"
Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Grid.ColumnSpan` to span several columns.